# Expected number of times you need to sample 5 balls out of 12 balls consisting of 9 blue and 3 red, until you get 2 red in total.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, problem-solving

Problem: I have 12 balls in a bag consisting of 9 blue and 3 red. I randomly choose 5, (each combination is equally likely). Now I check to see among the 5 removed balls, if they are exactly 2 RED balls. Stop here if so. If not, put the 5 balls back into bag and shake. Keep repeating this process until you get 2 red balls.

I want to calculate the expected number of times you need to removed the 5 balls from this bag, until you get your desired result.

I am struggling to understand, what distribution this could be? It's obviously not binomial, but I don't see what else it could be.

Please help - :)

Comment: Since each trial is independent of the others, this is just a geometric process.

Comment: Writing "2 red in total" is not totally clear when you mean "exactly two reds among the five in one drawing".

Comment: The probability of drawing exactly 2 red balls is $\binom 32\binom 93/\binom {12}5$. The distribution is geometric, so the mean is the reciprocal of this probability.

Comment: Could you explain how you got the numerator?